# Sending JPG image using OpenCV and Winsock (client in C++, server in Python)

Tags: python, c++, opencv, jpeg, winsock

I have an application written in C++ that captures depth data from a camera and converts it to a JPG image using OpenCV. While initially this application was just used to write the JPG images out to individual files (depth frames) to build a dataset, I now need to modify the application to send each depth frame to a neural network (written in python) running on the same machine. The OS for the machine is Windows.

I'm trying to use Socket communication to facilitate the IPC, but I'm stuck on trying to get Winsock to accept the data for the image that I want to send. I would like to encode the Mat object from OpenCV as a JPG and send it directly. However, the `send` function for winsock will only accept data that is a `const char*` buffer, and OpenCV will only encode the image into a `std::vector<uchar>` data type.

I've tried to convert from one type to the other. I've tried to access the data in the vector with `vector.data`, but I get this compiler error:

```
Error C3867 'std::vector<uchar,std::allocator<uchar>>::data': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member
```

I've also tried using `reinterpret_cast<const char*>`, but it throws an additional 6 compiler errors on the attempt.

I can't believe it would be this difficult to send an image file over a socket connection. Anyway, here's the relevant code I'm attempting to use (this is not for the final version of the application - this is a test file to try to get the process to work with a single image):

Load a test image as a Mat object and encode it before transfer:

```
cv::Mat image = cv::imread("testfile.jpg");
std::vector<uchar> imgbuf;
cv::imencode(".jpg", image, imgbuf);
```

Attempt to send it through my socket connection:

```
iResult = send(ConnectSocket, imgbuf.data, imgbuf.size(), 0);
```

Please let me know what I might be missing here.

Comment: When I try that the compiler says "argument of type 'uchar' is incompatible with parameter of type 'const char*'".

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out I had set up my OpenCV libraries wrong in Visual Studio 2019. I changed my compiler from x86 to x64, re-installed the libraries properly, and sent the data with:

```
iResult = send(ConnectSocket, (const char*)&imgbuf[0], imgbuf.size(), 0);
```

After this, everything compiled and transmitted fine.

For completion's sake, if anyone is interested in receiving and decoding the image on the Python side, the following Python code worked.

```
image = np.frombuffer(total_data, np.uint8)
image = cv2.imdecode(image, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
cv2.imshow('received image', image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

**Note**: many examples online use `np.fromstring` instead of `np.frombuffer` in the code above. This gave me a depreciation error and halted execution of my program.